# Disable button from clicking the parent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am building a Material UI app. I have a card component and I need to make it clickable. But there is also a button on the top right corner which edits the card on click. The problem is, when I click on that button, it'll handle 2 actions:

- the edit action called on the button itself
- clicks the card

Here is a snippet of code:

```js
<CardActionArea href={`/${item.name}`}>
  <Card key={index}>
    <CardHeader
      action={
        <Fab color="secondary" onClick={handleClick}>
          <EditIcon color={"primary"} />
        </Fab>
      }
    />

    <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
      <Avatar className={classes.avatar} alt={item.name} src={item.avatar} />
      <Typography variant="h6" color="textSecondary">
        Card description
      </Typography>
    </CardContent>
  </Card>
</CardActionArea>
```

How could I achieve that?

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (better on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put the FabIcon outside the clickable area of the Card and use absolute positioning to it into position?

Comment: Use `handleClick(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...}`

Comment: @ChrisG, thanks, that's exactly what I need. Do you by any chance know how to prevent this hover effect on click? The card is not clicked now, but there's still a hover effect

Comment: Not sure; did you try Prãtéék's suggestion?

Comment: @ChrisG It could be the case if the button was placed independently but it is a part of the card header props (action). Anyway, your solution is more sophisticated

Comment: Per the Material Design spec, you shouldn't be using FAB's on cards. Use an IconButton instead. https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button#usage

Answer (score 0):

In the card component you create both functions you want to run when clicking the card and the inner button:

```js
const onCardClick = () => {
  // your code here
}

const onButtonClick = () => {
  onCardClick()    
  // your code here
}
```

In Card.jsx when rendering the button inside the card add the `onButtonClick` function

```html
<MyButton onClick={onButtonClick}
```

then in your button component, you give it an onClick prop:

```js
const MyButton = (props) => {
  <Button onClick={prop.onClick}>title</Button>
}
```